# How is using this graph different from using this other graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming

**Question:**

> Given $n$ numbers $a_1,...,a_n$ find indices $i$ and $j$, $1 ≤ i ≤ j ≤ n$, such that $\sum\limits_{k=i}^{j}a_k$ is minimized. We will develop two algorithms for this problem that run in linear time, i.e., the number of (arithmetic) operations is linear in n.
>
> Solve the problem using Bellman-Ford as a subroutine. In particular, construct a graph such that a shortest path in this graph yields the optimal solution to the above problem. Show that the graph can be generated in linear time and that Bellman-Ford can be implemented to run in linear time on this graph.

**Answer:**

[image: two graphs that work]

**My question:**

Why is the second graph more efficient for the case where some of the $a_i$ are negative? I don't see the difference in those two graphs when it comes to the exercise...

Comment: Well, don't you mean (1st paragraph) "$\sum_{k=i}^j a_k$"? On a more general note, this problem becomes nontrivial only if some of the $a_k$s are negative and some are positive, otherwise you could just take the smallest $a_k$ (as you already noted).

Comment: Yes thank you for the correction. Well I get that, but how are those two graphs different?

Comment: Well, conceptually they really aren't. The graph on the left is formed by replacing each vertex $u$ in the middle row on the graph on the right with the arc $(u1,u2)$ of length 0.

Comment: Take the graph on the left, collapse each arc of length 0 to a single vertex, and you will get the graph on the right